# How i can remove the .php extension in .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

> My URLs like http://example.com/login.php and i want its shows like
>   http://example.com/login In my website first page is login.php rather
>   than index  so i have set this option in .htaccess
>
> Here is .htaccess file code

```
ErrorDocument 403 403.php
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 405 405.php
ErrorDocument 501 501.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [R=501,L]


Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex login.php

<LimitExcept GET POST>
deny from all
</LimitExcept>
ServerSignature Off 
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_reqtimeout.so>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>



    Header set X-FRAME-OPTIONS SAMEORIGIN 
    Header set Content-Security-Policy: "child-src 'self' allow 'self'; media-src *; img-src *; "
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer | same-origin | origin | strict-origin | no-origin-when-downgrading"
    Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: no i have another case also where i have to set first page is login.php

Comment: Its working after adding below lines.. RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] but the case is its not automatically redirectly to without extension URL. I have to manullay remove the .php from the url and then hit the enter its loading the page but my requirement is automatically redirecting to the without extension url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
# To externally redirect without .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Comment: When i am using then in that case POST data is not working. If am trying to send form data one page to another then in that case request is not sent. For instance, I have a login.php page where i have form there data send to login_register.php page using POST method but after using the rewrite condition which are writing in that case form data is not reached on that page

Comment: Send your data to "login_register" without ".php"